# I have varchar column with "2022-11-30T17:30:00.000Z" format how can i transform it to timestamp with time zone column in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, datetime-format, timestamp-with-timezone

We are storing date time in "2022-11-30T17:30:00.000Z" format in var char column i know its totally wrong but I want to rectify the mistake and use the column as timestamp with time zone.

I Tried using  column::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Calcutta'  but still date and time is wrong as it does not considers +5:30 in my time zone.please suggest how can i transform the column or if i could use the same column.

`select dtm from dashboard where (select dtm::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Calcutta')::date between '2022-11-30'   and '2022-11-30'  order by dtm;`

Comment: Please write a simpler query that doesn't rely on invisible tables, and then show us what you got vs what you wanted.  Maybe you want to cast dtm to timestamptz rather than timestamp.  Or maybe not.

Comment: Two things in your query are unclear: 1) what is the time zone in which the strings in the table are to be understood? Is that UTC or Indian time? 2) In what time zone are the date literals in your query to be understood?